# Is there a way to use the trackpad as an entire screen pointer jumper?

Tags: macos, touchpad

Instead of using the trackpad to move the pointer from the location it is currently in, is there a way to use it more like an entire-screen pointer? That is, I touch the middle of the trackpad and it puts the pointer on the middle of the screen? I'm on OS X Lion.

Comment: Technically: Yes it is possible. The software or drivers needed for it might be a challenge.  The closest thing I can find that I ever used it a Wacom tablet, which could be set up as a mouse or with absolute positioning.

Comment: Will you be using it in conjunction with another pointing device? Because if not, please realize that you probably won't be able to get to every pixel on the screen; the resolution of a trackpad is probably just a fraction of the resolution of your screen, so you may hit situations where the closest trackpad point is, say, 5 pixels away from the place you want to point.

Answer (score 1):

[Inklet](http://tenonedesign.com/inklet.php) is what you are looking for. It works like a charm on OSX, but it's a paid application. Well worth the money if you use it.

You can use it full-screen, or assing a region on screen where you want to draw. And if you have a capacitive stylus, you can even use that for sketching or writing.

I never found a Windows counterpart, though. I'd love to use my trackpad as a simulated full-screen touch panel. But never found a way for that...

(I'm not affiliated to Inklet any way.)